# Statistics Dummy Variable as Dependent Variable Regression

Tags: statistics, regression, dummy-data

I have a bunch of independent variables: height, weight, etc that I want to regress a dummy variable on to. For instance, if I wanted to regress diabetes (0 if patient doesnt have diabetes, 1 if patient does have diabetes) and I wanted to figure out the effect of an increase in 1 pound of weight on the probability of having diabetes, how would I do that? I'm sure there are multiple ways of doing it but I just never have heard of a model that does this.  I thought it was the probit model but I'm not sure. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing is known as logistic regression; a web search for that should turn up a lot of hits. Most commonly, the response is some function of a linear combination of inputs, but more generally, the response could be a nonlinear function of inputs.

The dependence of the response on an input (e.g. weight) is interesting, but not exactly well-posed, since the change of the probability of the response varies over the range of the input variable; the change is very small for very large or very small values of the input, and reaches some maximum in between.

Comment: so i should use a logit model then? above is just an example. im not actually using diabetes as my dependent. will the coefficients of that model give me probabilities?

Comment: @Pcarlitz yes, logit is worth considering, so is probit; there are other variations on the idea. The coefficients of a logit model tell the slope of log(p/(1 - p)) (you can confirm that yourself); that makes it a little bit easier to explain, although not much.

Comment: ok great. do you know of anyway I can convert the coefficients to probabilities easily using stata?

Comment: @Pcarlitz sorry, I don't know anything about Stata.